# Trying to add new layer to my build, can anyone sort out the problem?

Tags: linux, build, yocto, bitbake, recipe

~/rdk/build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid$ bitbake-layers add-layer meta-new
Specified layer directory doesn't exist

its continuously showing this error, I don't understand the reason, since it showed directory doesn't exist i tried to create a directory of same name as the above mentioned layer, still its showing same error. Please help I am new to Custom Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a new layer you will first need to create it

> bitbake-layers create-layer <PATH_TO_YOUR_NEW_LAYER>

> bitbake-layers create-layer ../sources/meta-new

then you need to add it

> bitbake-layers add-layer <PATH_TO_YOUR_NEW_LAYER>

What add-layer do is actually adding a new line in "build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid/conf/bblayers.conf" with the path of the new layer.

More documentation related to this topic [here](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/custom-meta-layers-recipes-images-in-yocto-project)

Comment: Thanks it helped, i was thinking add layer would create a new layer, since bitbake-layers create-layer dint work for me i manually created a layer, then i used add layer, it worked.!!